# Rotation of Oculus Touch Controller in A-Frame / Three.js

Tags: controller, rotation, touch, aframe, oculus

Does anyone know how to find the current rotation of an Oculus Touch Controller? - in A-Frame, or more likely combination of A-Frame and Three.js.
I want the current rotation to use it to control other objects.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Getting the controller position and rotation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/rotation.html#getting-rotation) is the same as any other entity via DOM:

```
 el.getAttribute('rotation');
```

or THREE.js:

```
 el.object3D.rotation
```

[Example logging rotation in console](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/bead-ablaze-bongo?path=index.html%3A13%3A63)

Comment: Thanks very much, this solved my problem. Unlike the Camera which is part of three.js, I didn't know how to access the controllers!

Comment: No problem. Marking the question as correct is appreciated